# Angular JS - Losing scope after creating new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm not a big fan of appending multiple variables onto a function, directive, etc. I'd rather have a single argument and handle missing elements on the tier making use of the variable. This typically makes the function more non-DRY friendly and, generally, works great. However, I appear to have cut off my scope - the changes to 'isAllowedToSeeMostPopularOption/CorrectOption' only bubble up as far as the statusBar.resultsDisplay and don't continue to the $scope.quiz. Is that something I'm going to have to manually handle or am I missing a way of not cutting off the bubble.

Controller calling the directive (top tier):

```
$scope.statusBar.resultsDisplay = updateResultsDisplayArgs();

updateResultsDisplayArgs = function () {
        if ($scope.quiz) {
            return {
                optionListHeader: str.get('quiz.answers'),
                options: [
                    { model: $scope.quiz.isAllowedToSeeMostPopularOption, label: str.get('quiz.allowed-to-see-popular-answer') },
                    { model: $scope.quiz.isAllowedToSeeCorrectOption, label: str.get('quiz.allowed-to-see-correct-answer') }
                ]
            }
        } else {
            return {};
        }
    }
```

Directive syntax:

```
<option-list-dropdown directive-args="statusBar.resultsDisplay"></option-list-dropdown>
```

Directive:

```
module.exports = ng(function () {
return {
    scope: {
        directiveArgs: '='
    },

    templateUrl: templateUrl,

    controller: 'optionListDropdownController'
};
```

});

Directive Controller:

```
var str = require('str-js'),
_ = require('lodash'),
CONST = require('../../../common/const.json'),
questionUtils = require('../question-utils'),
questionStatuses = CONST.questionStatuses,
questionTypes = CONST.questionTypes;

module.exports = ng(function ($scope) {
var generateGuid = function () {
    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
          .toString(16)
          .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
      s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

_.extend($scope, {
    questionStatuses: questionStatuses,
    questionTypes: questionTypes,
    optionListTooltip: str.get('quiz.results-display-tooltip'),
    optionsListId: 'option_list_' + generateGuid(),
    doThings: function (zz) {

    }

});
```

});

Directive syntax:

```
<ul>
    <li><label class="label" str="quiz.answers"></label></li>
    <li ng-repeat="option in directiveArgs.options">
        <input id="{{ optionsListId  + '_' + $index }}" type="checkbox" ng-model="option.model">
        <label class="label" for="{{ optionsListId  + '_' + $index }}">{{ option.label }}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

SHORTENED VERSION:
I really think something I'm doing here is causing my problem - the changes bubble up and change the $scope.statusBar.resultsDisplay. It's as though the creation of a new object with select elements of $scope.quiz is breaking the scope bubbling path:

```
$scope.statusBar.resultsDisplay = updateResultsDisplayArgs();

updateResultsDisplayArgs = function () {
    if ($scope.quiz) {
        return {
            optionListHeader: str.get('quiz.answers'),
            options: [
                { model: $scope.quiz.isAllowedToSeeMostPopularOption, label: str.get('quiz.allowed-to-see-popular-answer') },
                { model: $scope.quiz.isAllowedToSeeCorrectOption, label: str.get('quiz.allowed-to-see-correct-answer') }
            ]
        }
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce your code? You seem to have an idea for what *might* be happening  - can you reproduce with a short illustrative example, saving us the need to parse through your code-specific logic?

Comment: Updated accordingly. There's a very particular spot in the code that I think is breaking the link.